# How to set Image background color for images(gridview) using react-native-super-grid

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-super-grid to show the grid image. I need to set the background color for each image before load image in the grid.

Here is my code:

```
<GridView 
  spacing={5} 
  itemDimension={gridWidth} 
  items={this.renderItems()} 
  style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}} 
  renderItem={this.renderGrid.bind(this)} 
/> 

// Render grid method 
renderGrid() { 
  return(
    <ImageBackground 
      style={{backgroundColor:'#D1D1D1', aspectRatio:4/5}}
    >
      <FastImage 
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain} 
        source={{uri: item.uri}}
      /> 
    </ImageBackground> 
  ) 
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: <GridView
      spacing={5}
      itemDimension={gridWidth}
      items = {this.renderItems()}
      style={{backgroundColor: ‘white’}}
      renderItem={this.renderGrid.bind(this)}
      />
Render grid method
renderGrid(){
return(
 <ImageBackground style = {{backgroundColor:'#D1D1D1', aspectRatio:4/5}}>
        <FastImage 
          resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
          source={{uri: item.uri}}/>
        </ImageBackground  >
)
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use **onLoadEnd** prop and change the state if the image is loaded. Then, you can apply the style to **FastImage** directly, and use different style when image is loaded or still loading.

```
renderGrid() { 
  return(
    <ImageBackground>
      <FastImage 
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain} 
        source={{uri: item.uri}}
        style={imageLoaded ? styleWithoutBg : styleWithBg}
        onLoadEnd={() => this.setState({ imageLoaded: true })}
      /> 
    </ImageBackground> 
  ) 
}
```